# How to use self-signed SSL certificate in Xamarin.iOS and Universal Windows Platform?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, ssl-certificate, uwp, self-signed

I talk to my server using SSL, but have self-signed cert.

In Android I use this code to pass my SSL cert to system to be able make requests to my server:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(<byte [] my_ssl_data>); 
ks.load(in, <string mypassword>.toCharArray());
in.close();

TrustManagerFactory Main_TMF = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
Main_TMF.init(ks);

X509TrustManager Cur_Trust_Manager = new X509TrustManager()
{
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate [] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException { }
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate [] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException { }
    public X509Certificate [] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
};

SSLContext sslContext =  SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { Cur_Trust_Manager }, new SecureRandom());

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
{
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
    {
        try
        {
            Cur_Trust_Manager.checkServerTrusted((X509Certificate []) session.getPeerCertificates(), session.getCipherSuite());
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now I need something like this in Windows Universal App 8.1+ (Windows+WindowsPhone) and iOS 7.0+.

For network requests I use System.Net.Http.HttpClient which works both with UWP and Xamarin.iOS. I have cert from my server in DER format but still can't add a handler to HttpClient.

Xamarin.iOS version says "Not implemented"

```
HttpClientHandler myHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
certificate.Import(my_cert_der_bytes);
myHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
myHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
myHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpClient c = new HttpClient(myHandler);
....
```

UWP version unfortunately (and why the hell?) doesn't know  X509Certificate2 and all that stuff. I tried to use [WinRtHttpClientHandler](https://github.com/onovotny/WinRtHttpClientHandler) but didn't understand where should I pass my cert. I tried to skip errors (started to work), yet that's not a solution, because I don't want my requests to be redirected to another untrasted server.

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter(); 
Certificate cer = new Certificate(my_cert_bytes.AsBuffer());
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted); 
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired); 
WinRtHttpClientHandler myHandler = new WinRtHttpClientHandler(filter);
HttpClient c = new HttpClient(myHandler);
....
```

I suspect this is common task for most indies, certs are seldom for tests and small apps. But it seems task is made very difficult by platform devs. Is there any reliable solution?

Answer (score -1):

UWP apps cannot work with invalid (and self-signed) certificates. You may use Fiddler as proxy with fiddler's certificate for tests https.

Telerik Fiddler options - HTTPS - Capture HTTPS connects.

This work only on desktop not a mobile emulator.

Comment: this is not a solution, and my self signed cert is not a debug cert. I don't want to pay for cert, and want to avoid problems when cert will be expired or cert issuer site will be down